# Merging migration entries in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have an Entity Framework 6 CF project that has a few migrations already in place.

The model is now stable and there is no need to keep the migration history that already exists.

Is there a way to reset the model and merge all migration commands into the initial migration?

As an example, the first migration adds a column while the second migration adds a unique, non-clustered index. I now want to see all these changes directly in `OnModelCreating` rather than in separate migrations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Migrations have both an `Up` and `Down`. You can always Re-Scaffold your application by tearing the migrations down and then adding a new migration. The `Down` process does not change your model, only the changes to the database.  Use `Update-Database -Target:migrationTargetName` or `Update-Database -TargetMigration:migrationNumber`.

If you want a migration which starts with no database and ends with your current model, you can tear all the migrations down with `Update-Database -TargetMigration:0`.  It's a good idea to tear down the database and then run `Update-Database` as a test to verify the database changes are all in sync.

Bear in mind, if you tear your migrations down to `0` and then run an `Add-Migration`, you will want to look very closely at the generated scaffold, as it will likely be drastically different than the incremental changes.

Comment: Since I am unfamiliar with the terminology, here is  what I understand so far. Downgrading the database to migration `0`, will undo all `Up`s, execute all `Down`s and reset the DB to `InitialMigration`. How `Update-Database` will sync to the current database model is what I don't get. Will it generate a single `Up` and `Down` automatically such that the resulting model is what I had started with before tearing them down?

Comment: once you are at Migration `0`, you then want to run `Add-Migration` to create a new migration which starts from the current state (`0`) and scaffolds to your current model.  running `Update-Database` runs all the `Up` statements, which is useful for testing when you have many migrations.

Comment: It's likely I didn't phrase my intention clearly. We have `x` number of migrations currently and the consolidated hash is `abc` for example. I want to lose all the `Down`s and have either only one `Up` or the model itself updated such that the hash becomes `abc`. All records of migrations above the initial `0` should be discarded as if we had just run `InitialMigration` for the first time on the new model with hash `xyz`.

Comment: Not sure how to explain this clearly but it should be as if the current model should reflect the effects of all migrations but have no migrations :). Simply loose track of all migration steps while preserving the resulting model of all current migrations. Data loss is not a consideration of course.

Comment: Correct, moving the migrations down to `0` will leave you with no database, but does not change the model.  You can then add one single migration with the `Add-Migration` command, to bring the database to the state that the model is at.

Comment: Ah. So adding it would then be up to US to write the `Up` for that single migration? I'm assuming EF does not interpret code from discarded migrations for code-generation purposes. So if I added an index in migration `3`, I'd have to add it manually in he first migration after resetting?

Comment: The confusion above comes from your last paragraph which I interpreted to indicate 'generated' scaffolding. As if discarded migrations were taken into account for new code generation that we had to inspect. After all, the base model never changes until we manually change it. Or am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the "scaffolding" is the SQL commands in the `up` and `down` statements.  When you drop the database to the `0` migration with no database, then run a single `Add-Migration`, it will generate a single scaffold with `up` and `down` for the model in it's current state.  You then need to evaluate this carefully and verify that it matches your expected database schema, and add any custom SQL commands to this single Migration.

Comment: Hehe. Going to try this on a test model to see for myself. Upon dropping and performing `Add-Migration`, I'm hoping EF will try to consolidate all previous migrations (up and down sql commands) into the newly created migration. If that is the case, it would be easier (in my opinion) to CHANGE the model to reflect a single BLOB of changed SQL statements than to compare multiple versions of ups and downs.

Comment: Or, you can use the SQL Management Studio to script the current state of the database, then apply these scripts to any database you wish, ignoring the Migration classes completely.

Comment: The single migration will be similar to the previous group of migrations, but may not be 100% the same; it should be more efficient, without groups of table modifications.

Comment: Thank you! It's easier to phrase the question right when you know the answer :). That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to do this but keep the most recent migrations? The only way I can think of is to check out an old revision of my project from source control before starting—otherwise the “current” model will be too new. I just want EF to collapse migrations which I know are older than any instances of the database out there for the sake of cleaning things up without having to manually do it—is there no way?