# Official Way of merging existing database migrations in .NET Core 2.0 apps

Tags: .net-core, database-migration

Our ASP.Net Core 2.0 application now has over 30 database migrations (generated by using dotnet ef migrations add command), and those migrations have all been applied to the production database, as the development effort goes, we expect more migrations to be added to the app, my question is how we can properly merge the existing database migrations into one (we may called it PhaseOneMigrations) and still make it compatible to the migration management mechanism .NET Core team designed and also make the production database upgrade as smooth as possible.

More information can be provided upon request, and really appreciate the help.

== Updated on 3/24/2018 ==

We do came up with a tricky solution for this but it requires manually manipulate the __EFMigrationHistory table in the production database, it delivers the expected result though, the way is:

1. delete all migrations files, and recreate a new migration called Init, this migration contains latest schema, then add all necessary stored procedures creation script in the Up method.
2. delete all existing records in __EFMigrationHistory table in the production database and add one with the same name of the Init migration just created, thus EF core thinks this was the only migration.

But it's not official and we wonder if there is a supported way of doing this without manually touching __EFMigrationHistory table on the production server.

Comment: One that migrates from which version to which? The reason you need to keep multiple migrations is that you want to be able to migrate from any of the earlier versions to the latest one. You don't need migrations to create a *new* database that matches the latest schema

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the reply, our app is an online app which has only the latest version (we do not maintain multiple version of the app so every time we upgrade the app to a new version we always stick to the latest version of database), let's say we want to merge all migrations from the initial one to the latest one into a single migration, then we will keep adding new migrations, and one or two months later we will again merge the already-merged migrations with all later-added migrations into one, thus we keep the migrations to a manageable number of files.

Comment: If you don't want to *migrate* past a certain migration you don't need the previous migrations at all. You still need to keep enough migrations to match development, testing, QA environments

Comment: Check [Merging migration entries in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911015/merging-migration-entries-in-entity-framework). It isn't specific to EF Core though

Comment: Actually we do need the migrations for migrating our current database to the new version (forward migrations only, no backward migrations), and the migrations helped our dev team collaborate (we do code review and code merge on database migrations)

Comment: I'm not saying "remove migrations". I'm saying that you could remove *all previous* migrations once you are certain you no longer need them. That's what the linked answer shows too.

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos, but removing previous migrations will prevent the correct creation of the database on dev machines, the DB is created on the dev machine when we freshly clone our source repo to new dev machines, and sometimes developers do parallel feature developments which requires multiple version of databases on a single dev machine and they will create multiple DBs from the beginning. Please see the updated question as we came up with a tricky solution but I really don't like any manual operations to production DB.

Comment: It's what you are doing now though, by proxy. If you want versioning, branching and real schema diffs, you should use the Database Project from SSDT and version the database schema. It doesn't have to *replace* migrations. If you want to keep versions of the schema though, nothing beats, well, generating and keeping versions of the schema.

Comment: EF migrations is an example of well, migration-based database versioning. It works well with data migrations but doesn't handle merging that well as you found out. Versioning the actual database schema is an example of state-based versioning. It works well with schema versioning but needs manual intervention to handle data migration. YOU NEED BOTH. You can't apply every migration since a product's initial beta release to bring it up to v3.5.9 after all. Even the people that say they only use migrations, actually keep scripts of specific schemas so they don't have to apply every migration

Comment: What EF migrations gives you is an "automated" way to perform schema migrations. Apart from simple data migration cases though, you *still* have to write code for more complex cases, eg splitting one column to many, or extracting a common table to implement, eh inheritance. If EF wasn't involved, you'd use point migration scripts to move from vx.1 to vx.2. *Maybe* you'd write a major migration script to move from clean v1.0 to v2.0. Or, if the changes were too big, create a new schema and move the data. How long do you want your migration script to take?

Comment: You have to pick the proper technique for each scenario. There really is no silver bullet or one-size-fits-all. PS - this is worth a full blog post, if not a series of blog posts